# .Net Regex doesn't match when other tools do

Tags: c#, regex, match

I am trying to match on a string that begins with *./media*

I have the following Regular expression:

```
bool match = Regex.IsMatch(@"^\./media", imgSourcePath);
```

My source string looks like: *./media/somefile.png*

When I test this expression in other [tools](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) it works as expected. However a match is never found in C# source implementation. Can someone tell me why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameters appear to be backwards: `Regex.IsMatch(String input, String pattern)`.  Try this:

```
var m = Regex.IsMatch("./media", "(./media)(.*?)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | 
    RegexOptions.Singleline);
MessageBox.Show(m.ToString());  //displays true
```

Comment: OMG.. I had the regex and the input backwards. Dude.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0.aspx#Y30

You have the input and pattern backwards. The string you want to search for a match should be the first parameter, and the pattern to use should be the second.